# Missing right parenthesis when running on Oracle sql live

Tags: oracle, foreign-keys, ddl, create-table, ora-00907

```
CREATE TABLE Enrollment
(
    OfferNo  NUMBER(10)  NOT NULL,
    StdNo    CHAR(11)    NOT NULL,
    EnrGrade NUMBER(3,2) NULL,

    CONSTRAINT EnrollmentPK 
        PRIMARY KEY (OfferNo, StdNo),
    CONSTRAINT OfferingFK 
        FOREIGN KEY (OfferNo) REFERENCES Offering
                ON DELETE CASCADE
                ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT StudentFK 
        FOREIGN KEY (StdNo) REFERENCES Student
                ON DELETE CASCADE
                ON UPDATE CASCADE
);
```

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the columns the constraints refer to:

```
CREATE TABLE Enrollment(
    OfferNo       NUMBER(10)       NOT NULL,
    StdNo         CHAR(11)      NOT NULL,
    EnrGrade      NUMBER(3,2)  NULL,
    CONSTRAINT EnrollmentPK PRIMARY KEY (OfferNo, StdNo),
    CONSTRAINT OfferingFK FOREIGN KEY (OfferNo) REFERENCES Offering(OfferNo)
    -- Here --------------------------------------------------------^
                          ON DELETE CASCADE
                          ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT StudentFK FOREIGN KEY (StdNo) REFERENCES Student(StdNo)
    -- And here ------------------------------------------------^
                          ON DELETE CASCADE
                          ON UPDATE CASCADE
);
```